# Sort booleans, O(N) time, O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, boolean

For a homework assignment, I am asked to sort an array of bools using a method that uses O(1) space, and O(N) time complexity. Can any hints be offered? I was thinking of something along the pivot method of a quicksort algorithm. 
-Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Search for "bucket sort"

Comment: Your thought about the pivot method is basically the way to do it

Comment: Thought about that, although bucket sort will use O(N) space

Comment: Hint #2: It's all about counting

Comment: If there are only two values, to partition them is to sort them.

Comment: As an interesting observation for anyone reading. Suppose you wanted to generalize this problem to sorting an array where each element is from a set of three values, such as 0, 1, 2. Then, you could count number of 0's, 1's, and 2's and make a new array properly initialized based on the counts. If you generalize further, I would argue that this idea gives rise to Bucket sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Keep an index at the front and back.
2. check the current front index, if it's false increment the front index
3. if it's true swap with the back index and decrement the back index
4. continue with steps 2 and 3 until front and back indices are equal to each other

Comment: valid, efficient, but easier to miscode than simple count then assign approach

Comment: @RichardPlunkett it's virtually the same as the partition in a qsort, if you can't code that you shouldn't be a programmer, also it only makes one pass

Answer (score 5):

If you have an array of booleans, you can simply count the *true* (or *false*) values. Lets assume this results to *k*. Then you set the first *k* elements of the array to *true* and the remaining *false*.

This algorithm iterates through the array twice (so it has an *O(N)* time complexity), and only uses one counter, so the space required is *O(1)*.

Answer (score 2):

Since booleans only have two possible values, you can just count the "true"s and "false"s, and modify the original array in-place so that first you place the appropriate number of `false` values in it, then fill the rest with `true`. This is `O(n)` in time and `O(1)` in space, as required. C code follows:

```
void sortbool(int *b, size_t n)
{
    size_t k = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (!b[i])
                    k++;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            b[i] = !(i < k);
    }
}
```